# Function is returning NULL while dump show variable is set

Tags: php

Hello I have a silly problem. I want to parse `Firewall configuration file`. I have prepared a script which should display all ports from 1st entry from the file:

```
    $fileRule = file_get_contents("configurationfile.w");
    $rules = explode(":rule (",$fileRule);
    $rules = array_slice($rules,1,-1);



    foreach($rules as $rule){
        $ports = array();
        if (strpos($rule,'RULE')){
            $serv = getServices($rule);
            $ports = getPorts($serv);
            var_dump($ports);
            exit;break;
        }   

    }
```

function getServices($rule) return an array (checked with `var_dump`) and variable `$serv` is set properly.however somehow result of function `getPorts($ports` is null.

```
    function getPorts($serv){
        $fileObjects = file_get_contents("objects.C");
        $portss = array();
        $ref = array();
        foreach ($serv as $servPoint){
            $portAll = getBetween($fileObjects,": ($servPoint",":type (");
            if (strpos($portAll,': (ReferenceObject')){
                $portExploded = explode(": (ReferenceObject",$portAll);
                $portExploded = array_slice($portExploded,1);
                foreach($portExploded as $refPort){
                    $refName = getBetween($refPort,":Name (",")");
                    array_push($ref, $refName);
                }
                getPorts($ref);
            }
            else{
                $portAll = getBetween($fileObjects,": ($servPoint",":updated_by_sd");
                $port = getBetween($portAll,":port (",")");
                $type = getBetween($portAll,":type (",")");
                array_push($portss,array($port,$type));
            }
        }

        return $portss;
    }
```

I have checked variable `$portss` (return in the `getPorts`) and `echoed` it and variable contains proper set of values, however it is not being passed after it leave the function.

Can anyone give me a hint What am I missing?

**EDIT**
result of `var_dump($portss)` inside `getPorts()`

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "666"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "RDP"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "667"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "RDP"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "668"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "RDP"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "669"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "RDP"
  }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `exit` before the return statement causing your script to stop execution. Remove it, perhaps?

Comment: I will edit the question, exit and echo was set for test pourpose only to show that this variable is set. After removing it `$port` in the main is still null

Comment: `var_dump($portss);` inside your `getPorts()` function. What does it output?

Comment: I am adding result of var_dump inside getPorts() in the end of the quesion

Comment: It seems the problem is because is a recursive function and last execution returns an empty array

Comment: can you show me the code of getBetween function ...Is the getBetween function returning an array ??

Comment: @CodeLover Im 100% sure getBetween return an array, however if You want I can post the code (it is simple 2 time explode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible that in the last execution of the function `getPorts` (remember that it's a recursive function) you have all the data and do not return it to the main function.

I think the problem it's that in the last execution of the function you return the variable `$portss` but it's empty because you set it at the start of the function.

In recursive function you need to recover data returned from the *inside* functions, so you can do some things (i can't give you a direct answer because don't know the file you are parsing)

1.- Change this: `getPorts($ref);` to this `$portss = getPorts($ref);` this way you recover the data from other executions of the function.

2.- Pass the returned variable, `$portss` as a parameter to the function, so you can access it in the very last execution of it.

Comment: Did the 1st step, although I do not understand the second. (no result)

Comment: The second step is another way to do the same, it works with the first solution?

Comment: Actually it works now :) I have created another attribute to the function getPorts($port,$portss) then delete initialization of array and in recursive function i call as getPorts($ref,array()) Thank You @Sal00m !